# I don't understand exactly this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

I read this sentence [on this image](http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/02/85/14/0285141f34df458170415440e3f9ea0e.jpg) :

> She smelled **of** sun and daisies with **a hint** of river water.

I don't get at all why do we say "She smelled **of**", why is there "of" after smelled ? Couldn't we get rid of that ?
My other question is about "a hint", although I think that I understand what it means, I would appreciate to have the opinion of you guys.

Comment: I'd probably wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer - this encourages other people to answer, which might result in a better answer than mine!

Comment: @jimsug Ok I'll to it next time.

Comment: It may help you to note that this use of ***hint*** is simply a metaphorical extension from the more "literal" sense *hint = clue, suggestion, implication, slight indication*, etc. Although it can be "translated" / paraphrased as *a small amount* here, that's not really what the word "means". Much the same applies to ***trace***, which is synonymous in OP's context (but "literally" refers to the *trail, vestiges, marks, footprints* left by something that passed through).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Smelling *something* means you're doing the smelling, and the thing you're smelling is *something*.
- Smelling **of** *something* means that you smell, and what you smell **like** is *something*

> She smelled **of** ...

She smelled **like**

> ... sun and daisies with **a hint** of river water.

With *a small amount* of river water

Collins:

[hint (3)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hint)

> a small amount; trace

Answer (score 6):

There is a marked difference between smelling something and smelling *of* something.

If you "smell" sun and daisies - you detect the odor of sun and daisies.
If you "smell *of*" sun and daisies - you *emit* the odor of sun and daisies. Others around you will "smell" sun and daisies.

Alternative wordings could be "smell like" or "smell similar to".

When referring to smell a "hint" of something means that scent (or as in this case *aspect* of the scent) is faint.

Comment: Thank you ! Unfortunately, although I now understand the difference between "smelling something" and "smelling of something" I still don't understand what you mean about the hint !

Comment: You mentioned you thought you understood what it meant; could you elaborate on what you thought/think it was? If you're close it might be easier to explain from there.

Comment: In fact as jmsung told, I was thinking that it was "a small amount", so I was right ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered the "smell of" part.

When you say "a hint of X", you mean just a small amount of X, or that X is there but difficult to detect. Like if you said, "This cake contains a hint of chocolate", that means that it is NOT a chocolate cake, but there is a small amount of the taste of chocolate to it. Or I heard a politician just recently say that "there is not a hint of corruption" in his actions. He means, there is not the smallest, tiniest amount of corruption.

Note that this sentence is not literal. She might smell like daisies, but she probably does not literally smell like the sun. I don't think river water really has a distinctive smell, either. It's all a poetic way to say that she reminds one of pleasant things from nature.